# Using SendKey in NSL

Tags: novell

All,

If anyone has experience working on NSL (Novell SecureLogin), I am trying to use the command SendKey "\|123" to send the F12 command, but there is no subsequent action taking place and nor any error. I tried googling out, but could not find much help. I have tried SendKey "{F12}" and SendKey ("{F12}") as well. Can anyone please let me know the appropriate command used to issue F12 key command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using it via `Type` instead of Sendkey?

Comment: No I haven't and I would try now. But do you suggest that it cannot be done with Sendkey ?

Comment: If it is not working in Sendkey, then test with `Type` to see.  `Type` is preferred over `Sendkey`.